# How to Convert Dicom file url into filelist

Tags: javascript, angular

[image]

Dicom Url is in the viewFile variable, when i pass it into the LoaddicomImages function it gives error only  data of type filelist needs to be passed into the function. I cannot change the filelist type of the argument of the function because it is mandatory to keep the type filelist.

```
export class ViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(DICOMViewerComponent, { static: true }) viewPort: DICOMViewerComponent;

  viewFile: any;
  
  

  constructor(private router: Router)
  {
    this.viewFile = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state['item'];
    console.log(this.viewFile);
    
    
      }

  ngOnInit() {
    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone; // inicializa WADO Image loader
    
    // configura codecs e web workers
    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.webWorkerManager.initialize({
        webWorkerPath: './assets/cornerstone/webworkers/cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderWebWorker.js',
        taskConfiguration: {
            'decodeTask': {
                codecsPath: '../codecs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderCodecs.js'
            }
        }
    });
    this.loadDICOMImages(this.viewFile)
  }
 

  /**
   * Load selected DICOM images
   *
   * @param files list of selected dicom files
   */
  loadDICOMImages(files : FileList) {
      console.log(files)
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      let imageList = [];
      const fileList:Array<File> = Array.from(files);
      fileList.sort((a,b) => {
        if ( a.name > b.name ) return 1;
        if ( b.name > a.name ) return -1;
        return 0;
      })
      cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.fileManager.purge();
      // cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.dataSetCacheManager.purge();

      // loop thru the File list and build a list of wadouri imageIds (dicomfile:)
      for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        const dicomFile: File = fileList[i];
        const imageId = cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.fileManager.add(dicomFile);
        imageList.push(imageId);
      }

      this.viewPort.resetAllTools();

      // now load all Images, using their wadouri
      this.viewPort.loadStudyImages(imageList);

    } else alert('Choose DICOM images to display.');
  }

}
```